# React type number textInput replace comma

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
    <TextInput
      onChange={(price) => setData({ price: price.replace(/\,/g, ".") })}
      value={data.price}
      type="number"
    />
```

I want only number as the input value and if a user enters a comma, I want to replace it with dot. How can I do this ?

Comment: how user can type "/" inside input with `type="number"` ?

Comment: @b3hr4d why do you expect that?

Comment: I didn't expect that, check the question.

Comment: @b3hr4d that's what confused me. he's querying a regular expression matching a comma and replacing it with a dot, though the escaping character before the comma is unnecessary since comma doesn't have a special meaning in regex

Comment: that's right! I mean when you just allow to typing number, how can type "/" or ","?

Comment: @b3hr4d it's browser dependant. some browsers allow you to enter letters as well. chrome only allows for "e" to enable E-Notation. comma or period are both widely used for decimals and are allowed in general. but I don't understand why you're asking for "/". the question doesn't include a search for it.

Comment: Sorry I just want to show a symbol as an example.